# Struts2 - Strange behavior of ModelDriven Interface

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, model-driven

My objective is to get an object of TestBean class in Struts2 Action and show its values at jsp page (view layer)

I am implementing ModelDriven interface into my action class as follows

```
public class TestAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<TestBean>{

    private TestBean testBeanObject;

    @Override
    public TestBean getModel() {
        return testBeanObject;
    }

    @Override
    public String execute(){

        testBeanObject = getting object of TestBean Class from business layer (It is having all the value whatever I want)

        return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

My TestBean class code

> @Entity
>
> ```
> @Table(name="test_bean") 
> public class TestBean implements Serializable { 
> private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; 
>
> @Id 
> @Column(name="test_bean_id") 
> private int testBeanId; 
>
> private String firstProperty; 
>
> private String secondProperty; 
>
>
> @OneToMany(mappedBy="testBeanPaper", fetch = FetchType.LAZY) 
> private List<PapersText> papersTexts; 
>
> public TestBean() { 
> } 
>
> public String getFirstProperty() { 
>    return this.firstProperty; 
> } 
>
> public void setFirstProperty(String firstProperty) { 
>    this.firstProperty = firstProperty; 
> } 
>
> public String getSecondProperty() { 
>    return this.secondProperty; 
> } 
>
> public void setSecondProperty(String secondProperty) { 
>    this.secondProperty = secondProperty; 
> } 
>
> public List<PapersText> getPapersTexts() { 
>    return this.papersTexts; 
> } 
>
> public void setPapersTexts(List<PapersText> papersTexts) { 
>    this.papersTexts = papersTexts; 
> }
> ```
>
> }

My jsp page code is

```
<s:textarea id="textarea1" class="longinput" name="firstProperty" value="%{firstProperty}"></s:textarea> 

<s:textarea id="textarea2" class="longinput" name="secondProperty" value="%{secondProperty}"></s:textarea>
```

At View Layer (Jsp page) I am having text fields with same name as properties of TestBean Class.

Now the problem is

**case 1.**

If I am getting TestBean class object form another class (as shown above), Values are not reflecting at jsp page. Even TestBean object is initialized perfectly

**case 2.**

In action class, If I manually set value of properties of TestBean class like

```
testBeanObject.setFirstProperty("FirstProperty");
testBeanObject.setSecondProperty("SecondProperty");
```

It is reflecting perfectly at view layer.

I have debugged my code. It is showing that object is initialized and have correct values in both case.Then Why is it not reflecting in **case 1**.

Plz help

Comment: Try changing `private TestBean testBeanObject;` to `private TestBean testBeanObject = new TestBean();` . Initialize it.

Comment: Why do you use/need ModelDriven?

Comment: How do you access properties of `TestBean` in JSP?

Comment: There are a number of text fields on jsp page that i need to initialize.

Comment: The `name` attribute of `<s:textfield>` must match the corresponding property in the model - `TestBean`. Are you sure?

Comment: @Tiny If I am wrong here, then second case won't work.

Comment: Is it a bug in ModelDriven ??

Comment: This makes no sense :| You must be doing something wrong somewhere, that has been hidden by the cleaned up code posted, I guess... we need more details.

Comment: **Is TestBean lazily initialized ??**

Comment: @AndreaLigios yes it is

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52734/discussion-between-ankit-sharma-and-andrea-ligios)

Comment: wherre is the lazy initialization ? BTW +1 because you are showing effort

Comment: oops, I edited, plz check

Comment: Can you post the JSP snippet where you read it ? It's still weird... :)

Comment: @AndreaLigios I hv posted jsp page code, plz check...

Comment: I got the solution. In action class, I have written getter method of TestBean object variable and in jsp page I am accessing value of properties of TestBean object by  
<s:textarea id="textarea1" class="longinput" name="firstProperty" value="%{testBeanObject.firstProperty}"></s:textarea> 

Thank u @AndreaLigios for ur valuable time.. :)

Comment: Good... `“Once you eliminate the impossible, whatever remains, no matter how improbable, must be the truth.”` :)

Comment: In this way you are not using modeldriven approach.

Comment: @AleksandrM yes you are right, but I am initializing TestBean object only not all property of it in action class and there is no need to write getter method of all properties of TestBean Object ;)

Comment: You don't have to create getters methods for all properties of bean in action just for the bean. And don't have to use modeldriven.

Comment: @AleksandrM Yes, I am using same :)